# How to aggregate data with date range?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Hello I have the following problem, whenever I aggregate data, the aggregations and to be more exact the date_histogram is always different. It starts with pretty much random date.

I am using `elasticpy` and my query looks like this before executing. Note that I am using python datetime objects to get a "real" results. I had some problems with other formats.

```py
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "original_date": {
                            "gte": datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 13, 0, 0),
                            "lte": datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 15, 23, 0),
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must": [
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "whatever string"
                    }
                }
            ],
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "docs_histogram": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "original_date",
                "interval": "hour",
                "time_zone": "EET",
            },
            ... (other aggs)
        },
    },
}
```

The date histogram should be in this range: 2020-02-13 00:00:00 - 2020-02-15 23:00:00 But look at the output's start and end. It starts 1 day later and ends same day 18:00 ??

```py
"buckets": [
    {
        "key_as_string": "2020-02-14T00:00:00.000+02:00",
        "key": 1581631200000,
        "doc_count": 1,
        "source_name": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [{"key": "WhateverKey", "doc_count": 1}],
        },
    },
    ...
    {
        "key_as_string": "2020-02-14T18:00:00.000+02:00",
        "key": 1581696000000,
        "doc_count": 1,
        "source_name": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [{"key": "WhateverKey2", "doc_count": 1}],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Not sure what happens to the timestamps that you use in the query clause with respect to the dates. At least I can see the difference between UTC and EET somehow reflected in the first bucket (2h). Could it be that you don't have data, so that the first and last buckets are what they are?
I recommend that you first check your documents in the Kibana discover interface to see the timestamps stored in your docs. Please post some more inormation about your findings.

Comment: Yeah it is possible for the data to be empty at the specified period (for this query otherwise there are documents). But I think the point is to create empty buckets for these hours and start the aggregations from the specified range in this case 2020-03-13 00:00:00 and not a day later (sometimes it starts 3h later from the specified time, or pretty much random).
Also, there are empty buckets between these, I just added [...] to save space.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54942602/histogram-over-fixed-range-of-dates-i-e-fixed-number-of-buckets-even-when-dat/54943257#54943257) might be helpful.

Comment: @OpsterESNinjaNishant Thank you so much! It actually worked with the extended_bounds.

Comment: @Dimitar Glad it helped. Please up vote that answer.

Comment: @OpsterESNinjaNishant Already did that :)